# how to Save BMR results and read them again for analysis and plotting

Tags: mlr3

I wonder if it is possible to save BMR in an external file and read it later on for analysis and plotting.

Also, when multiple performance measures are used, can learners be ranked based on the multiple performance measures simultaneously? or Should learners be ranked on each measure separately then average the rank? Which approach is recommended?

Comment: 1. Use saveRDS (be sure to set the approriate flags `store_models` and `store_backends` if you need them later)2. this is not a programming question so you should ask somewhere elses

Answer (score 2):

For both questions use [mlr3benchmark](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3benchmark). I sent you yesterday a [tutorial](https://link.medium.com/4LRD9g23Onb) on how to use it for multiple performance measures. You can save the benchmark rds object with saveRDS (we will also add this as a method soon).